# Decoding json in Golang

Tags: json, go

I cannot figure out what's wrong in my code to decode this json. It returns an empty struct. Go playground here: http://play.golang.org/p/K8WznLT5M0

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type ApiParams struct {
    AccessToken string `json:access_token`
    TokenType   string `json:token_type`
    ExpiresIn   int64  `json:expires_in`
}

func main() {
    data := `{
            "access_token": "asdfasdf",
            "token_type": "bearer",
            "expires_in": 5173885
    }`

    var apiParams ApiParams
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &apiParams)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(apiParams)
}
```

Comment: I can't either until you tell me what output you expect.

Comment: What I get is `{  0}`, and what I expected is an instance of the struct ApiParams populated with the json in variable `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add double quotes to the tags:

```
type ApiParams struct {
    AccessToken string `json:"access_token"`
    TokenType   string `json:"token_type"`
    ExpiresIn   int64  `json:"expires_in"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why? I have another camel cased, as opposed to this underscored one. that one works without the double quotes.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen: it needs quotes, because that's the defined syntax. The CamelCase example works, because Go will map the names to lowercase while decoding if there is no tag defined.

Comment: Thanks @rightfold, I need to clarify when I talked about camel case, I meant the tag is in camel.

Answer (score 2):

Your annotations are wrong.. You need quotes around the json property names like;

```
type ApiParams struct {
    AccessToken string `json:"access_token"`
    TokenType   string `json:"token_type"`
    ExpiresIn   int64  `json:"expires_in"`
}
```